# If no parent key or different format of JSON file show error

Tags: jquery, json

I need to show json data and message if below conditions met by given URL or show error message.

**Conditions:**

> 1. One parent key must be present in given URL. Should not be more than one parent key.
>    If yes, show success message `<div id="success">Valid JSON file</div>`
> 2. Shuld show error message incase of requirements does not reach.
>
>    - If given URL has multiple parent keys (Eg: https://api.github.com/repositories/19438/commits)
>    - If no parent key found (Eg: https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs)
>    - If json file not found (Eg: https://lipsum.com/feed/html)

Then show error message `<div id="fail">Invalid JSON file</div>`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/aL7e3s0k/21/)

**Valid JSON data example**:

- https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list

**Invalid JSON data example**:

- https://amp.dev/static/samples/json/cart.json
- https://api.github.com/users/hadley/orgs
- https://api.github.com/repositories/19438/commits

> **Reference screenshots:**
> [image]

> [image: > [![enter image description here][3]][3]]

> [image]

```js
jQuery(document).on('keyup blur', '#rp-list-url', function (e) {
    var _self = jQuery(this);

    if (/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(_self.val())) {

        var atd, atr, temp, allKeysOnly = '', keyData = "", keyData = "";
        let resultData = [];

        var __jsonFile = _self.val();
        fetch(__jsonFile).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
            __findChildArrays(data);
            console.log(resultData);
            if (resultData && resultData[0]) {
                resultData[0].map(myList => {
                    var __keys = Object.keys(myList);
                    var __values = Object.values(myList);
                    $('#hiddenKeys').val(__keys);
                    $.each(__values, function (index, myList) {
                        atd = '<td>' + myList + '</td>'
                        atr += atd;
                        if ((__keys.length) - 1 == index) {
                            temp += '<tr>' + atr + '</tr>'
                            atr = '';
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
            $('#data table').html(temp);
            var __a = jQuery('#hiddenKeys').val();
            __a = __a.split(',');
            $.each(__a, function (index, item) {
                index = index + 1;
                keyData = '<div class="rp-key ' + item + '" id="key-' + index + '">{{' + item + '}}</div>'
                allKeysOnly += keyData;
            });
            $('#dataKeysContainer').html('<div class="all-keys-wrapper">' + allKeysOnly + '</div>');
        });
        var __findChildArrays = function (data = {}) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
                if (Array.isArray(data[key])) {
                    resultData.push(data[key])
                }
                else {
                    __findChildArrays(data[key] || [],)
                }
            });
            return resultData;
        };
        jQuery('#success').show();
        jQuery('#fail').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery('#success').hide();
        jQuery('#fail').show();
    }

    jQuery('#jsonFileName').html(__jsonFile);

});
```

```css
table, td{border:1px solid #333;border-collapse:collapse}
td{padding:5px;}
#success{color:green;}
#fail{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="rp-list-url" style="width:100%;" placeholder="URL for Json data" />
<br><br>
<div id="success" style="display:none;">Valid JSON file</div>
<div id="fail" style="display:none;">Invalid JSON file</div>

<div id="data">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenKeys" />

<div id="dataKeysContainer"></div>
<br>

<div>File name: <span id="jsonFileName"></span></div>
```

Comment: You say it should have only one key in the returned object, but https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/public/ssr_amp_list has two (`items` and `part_of_them`), and you say it is valid. Conversely, https://amp.dev/static/samples/json/cart.json only has one key (`items`) and you have it in the invalid list. Which one is correct?

Comment: "Valid JSON data example" contains two keys, which should be an Invalid JSON data example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code block once you receive the JSON data from the URL (after line 11 in JS):

```
if (data.length === undefined && Object.keys(data).length === 1) {
  jQuery('#success').show();
  jQuery('#fail').hide();
} else {
  jQuery('#success').hide();
  jQuery('#fail').show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, it is not working :(

Comment: Try the forked - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chw15psL/)